# Why is the scientific formatting of Decimal(0) different from float 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, decimal

When using `Decimal(0)` and formatting it to `.2e` format the following happens:

```py
>>> f'{Decimal(0):.2E}'
'0.00E+2'
```

However if you just use `0` or `0.` the following happens:

```py
>>> f'{0.:.2E}'
'0.00E+00'
```

How come the results are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous answer I described **how** this is done in cpython, in this I will describe **why**.
This question was raised in this [discussion](https://bugs.python.org/issue31684) and most of the quotes will be from there:

Let's consider an example:

```
>>> x = Decimal("1e+5").quantize(Decimal("1e+10"))
>>> x
Decimal('0E+10')
>>> s = "{:.19e}".format(x)
>>> s
'0.0000000000000000000e+29'
>>> Decimal(s)
Decimal('0E+10')
```

The original magnitude was `e+10`, after formatting it's still `e+10`.
The magnitude of the original number **is kept** after the formatting process.

> From the point of view of decimal it's the right thing. The original **magnitude should be traceable**

> `0` is really special in the IBM specification. The magnitude is
> kept, the precision is not.
>
> ```
> >>> Decimal("0e10") * Decimal("0e20") 
> Decimal('0E+30')
>
>
> >>> Decimal("0.000e10")
> Decimal('0E+7')
> ```
>
> So we're basically doing the reverse of the above in formatting when a
> precision is given.

---

So, if we go back to the original example of the OP:

```
>>> f'{Decimal(0):.2E}'
'0.00E+2'
```

If it returned `0.00Е+00` then the magnitude of this decimal number would be `E-2`:

```
>>> d = f'{Decimal(0):.2E}'
>>> d
'0.00E+2'
>>> Decimal(d)
Decimal('0')
>>> d = '0.00E+00'
>>> Decimal(d)
Decimal('0.00')
```